# Tempo no eixo X de gráficos C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho o seguinte gráfico no meu `Windows Form`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configurei o eixo X para exibir Tempo, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo os métodos que chamo para desenhar o gráfico:

```
        private void funcaoQualquer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                funcaoArray[funcaoArray.Length - 1] = hScrollBar1.Value;
                Array.Copy(funcaoArray, 1, funcaoArray, 0, funcaoArray.Length - 1);
                if (chart1.IsHandleCreated)
                {
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { atualizaGraficoFuncaoQualquer(hScrollBar1.Value); });
                }
                else
                {
                    //...
                }
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
        }

        private void atualizaGraficoFuncaoQualquer(int valor)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < funcaoArray.Length - 1; ++i)
            {
                chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(valor);
            }
        }
```

Porém ao desenhar o gráfico e com o passar do tempo, o eixo X não muda os valores. Acho que está sendo exibido como horas. Como faço para alterar para minutos ou segundos ?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código que está usando.

Comment: coloquei o código @jbueno